# how to have HTML text over image, or make background image responsive

Tags: css

I have a problem.

I am creating a responsive header image, that would scale down to mobile and take the full width of the screen.

I would like to have done this with the `img` tag, and then applied a max-width of 100% but I wanted to include some text on top of this image, so chose to use a background image instead. I don't want to absolute the text over the images as this causes problems in mobile.

Also, regarding background image, I can't use background-size as this is not supported in ie8.

Is there any other way I can achieve having text over an image, where the image takes full width of the container, and full height of the image?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="container" style="height: 100px; width:100px; display:block;">
  <img src="some-img.jpg" style="display:block;"/>
  <span style="position:absolute;">Text over image</span>
</div>
```

Essentially you just need to position the text over the image, within a parent.

`z-index` property is useful for "stacking" elements visually if you have several competing elements.

Comment: thanks, but I stated above that I wanted to avoid using absolute positioning, buy maybe there is no other way to do this

Comment: Ok so the OTHER answer is : Sure - but you'll need to manipulate the image on the serverside. Also realistically you could do this with css that is "relative" but it wouldn't make much sense as the layout implications of a "relative" set of text are much different than a contained "absolute"-ly positioned set. Can i ask - why are you unable to dynamically offset text that is not relatively positioned?